# Replace the first occurrence of the string using regex in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-ise

I was working some replace string using regex in powershell. 
But When I try to implement the first occurrence in the stringto replace a word. It does not work.

`(((Grant Execute.*)\n+go)(\n)?)` This is my working regex if I want to replace all the matches.

`^(((Grant Execute.*)\n+go)(\n)?)` I used this when I want to replace the first occurrence of the string...

Below is the string that I want to replace. This data is came from a batch file.

`Grant Execute on dbo.Table to server1 
go
Grant Execute on dbo.Table to server2 
go
Grant Execute on dbo.Table to server2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
(?s)(?<!go\s*)Grant Execute.*?go(?!\sGrant)
```